# How to return specific rows from a csv file and put them into array

Tags: php, csv, rows

I'm basically wondering how to get specific rows from a csv file (lets say the file has 5000 rows I want to get the values of the second column from rows 3023 - 3311). Upon obtaining these column values I want to put them into a php array.

What I've tried so far:

```
 $search = $this->uri->segment(3); // get the row number    
 $row1 = 0;

   if (($handle = fopen("Folder/Data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE)
    {
        while (($data1 = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
        {
            $num1 = count($data1); // number of data rows
            $row1++;
            for ($c=0; $c < $num1; $c++) {



                echo $data1[$c+1]; // to return second row


            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

But that only returns one single row and I need to return around 200 and put them into an array. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close.  You don't need to run a `for` loop inside of your `while` loop.  You can use something like this:

```
$file = fopen('/path/to/file', 'r');

// Helps us keep tabs on the row we are on
$rowCount = 0;
// Array that stores all of our column values.  In this case, I'll be gathering 
// values from the second column
$secondColumnArray = array();
while(false !== ($rowData = fgetcsv($file))){
    if($rowCount >= 50 && $rowCount <= 100){
        array_push($secondColumnArray, $rowData[1]);
    }
    $rowCount = $rowCount + 1;
}

print_r($secondColumnArray);

fclose($file);
```

In the above example, my array contains values from the second column of rows 50 to 100.  Change the parameters to fit your criteria.